# php exec() permissions - soffice command works in terminal but not in php exec()

Tags: php, apache, iis, permissions, exec

```
<?php // BISMILLAHIRRAHMANIRRAHEEM
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

// tried the following with soffice, soffice.com, soffice.exe, soffice.bin
// MS-DOS: soffice, soffice.com, soffice.bin all work successufully and generate the pdf
$ex = "soffice.com --headless --convert-to html \"" . getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "sources" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "test.docx\" --outdir \"" . getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "results\"";// 2>&1";

chdir("C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program");

echo $ex . "<br />";
exec($ex, $output);
//exec("mkdir rr", $output); // generates directory
//exec("dir soff*", $output);
//exec("a.bat", $output); // doesn't generate pdf
print_r($output);
?>
```

Hi, I'm using IIS with Windows 7, PHP 5.6.39. I am unable to convert a docx document to pdf by calling LibreOffice via PHP. The command output to screen in the code example works if executed in MS-DOS window but doesn't work in php's exec() or shell_exec(). The folder seems to have the appropriate permissions since my upload scripts and exec("mkdir newdir") are working.
`exec("dir");` also outputs directory listings for the mentioned path, so DOS navigation commands seem to work as well.

I'd like to [avoid the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244012/running-generate-pdf-soffice-libreoffice-on-windows-php-exec-doesnt-work) to make another user. Not elegant. This shouldn't be difficult INSHAALLAH.

By not working, I mean no document is generated and no output/ error is generated by `exec()` either which makes it difficult to debug.

Thank you for your time.

- Update:
  After some fiddling, I've realized the return code is: -1073741515
  Google results show that its apparently a File I/O failure.
  Another script I have downloaded which does something similar, also gave the same error. So looking into the causes. As I said before, the directories can be made and files uploaded as it has permissions.

In the link I've posted, there seems to be need for making new user. Is it possible that IIS has permissions to the directory but not the PHP `exec()`?

- On Linux, it gives me error code `77`, permission denied?

Comment: use single quotes, else the `\t` will result in a tab

Comment: Thank you. I have already fixed it where it was needed. This code, however, does result in directory listing for the path mentioned in `chdir()` when executing `dir` command.

Comment: Have you tried to set application pool identity to local system? If it works, then you set the application pool back and diagnose permission issue with process monitor

Comment: I used IUSR as kept in default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BISMILLAHIRRAHMANIRRAHEEM

ALHAMDOLILLAH after much search, finally found the answer.

### Windows:

I did some permissions etc earlier, should be trivial with IIS. But what finally solved the problem was [this](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/182108/not-able-to-launch-soffice-within-an-application-on-the-iis-server/).

Apparently there needs to be specified `-env:UserInstallation=file:///C:\some\path` because you cannot run multiple instances of LibreOffice concurrently without specifying a different profile folder ([Reference](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/7284/multiple-instances-for-c-automation/)).

Also, see the same solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901973/using-libreofficesoffice-exe-as-process-start-from-code-behind-not-working-o).

When executing a program via PHP over IIS, the user account for Windows is the IUSR account.

So,

1. Give IUSR write (and modify? I give full) permissions to be able to write to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\path` directory.
2. Change directory to LibreOffice path for `soffice.com` (Not needed if providing full path when executing):

```
chdir("C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program");
```

3. Set HOME environment variable, as LibreOffice needs a writable temporary path. IUSR must have permissions to this path. I simply re-use `wwwroot` (This step could be optional):

```
putenv("HOME=C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\temp");
```

4. Execute in PHP, something like:

```
exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.com\" --headless \"-env:UserInstallation=file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/LibreOfficeProfilePath1\" --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\result\" \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\source\\file.docx\"", $output, $ret);
// Displaying the command output
print_r($output);
echo "<br />\n\n<br />"; // Line breaks for view-source
echo "Return code: " . $ret;
```

5. Clean up by removing the profile directories for LibreOffice. Since you'd be making unique directories on-the-fly on a server environment for concurrent sessions of LibreOffice, you'd like to delete them too. Following snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250739/running-libreoffice-soffice-exe-on-windows-from-php-exec-stuck?rq=1):

```
exec("rmdir /S /Q \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\LibreOfficeProfilePath1\"");
```

You could look to generate this profile path automatically, like:

```
// Do this before executing soffice command and pass it to -env
$profilepath = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/LibreOfficeProfilePath" . date("YmdHis") . rand(0, 999999);
// Make sure to replace '/' with '\' when deleting
exec("rmdir /S /Q \"" . str_replace("/", "\\", $profilepath) . "\""); // Windows
exec("rm -rf \"" . str_replace("/", "\\", $profilepath) . "\"); // Linux
```

or instead use PHP to delete directory with files in it as shown [here](https://paulund.co.uk/php-delete-directory-and-files-in-directory).

LibreOffice running as a service and PHP requesting document conversions may be a better solution but this post relates to invoking LibreOffice each time a document conversion is needed and then letting it close. A separate process method may also be used to avoid waiting for LibreOffice to complete conversion.

### Linux:

- Similar steps for `www-data`, as that is the user account for apache in Linux. See the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/627266/convert-file-to-pdf-using-libreoffice-under-user-apache-i-e-when-using-php).
- www-data does not have $HOME directory so it needs to be specified as indicated in (3) above.
- `env` path would be something like:

```
\"-env:UserInstallation=file:///var/www/tmp\"
```

Notice the three `/` after `file:` regardless of Windows or Linux, even though paths in Linux start with `/`, or maybe they ignore the slash in Windows, seems inconsistent to me, though.

INSHAALLAH it'll work after that.